# how do the neurons get stronger physically?

Tags: neuroscience, memory, free-will

I wanna know about the possibility of simulating the brain state physically to know about the possibility of getting an answer for (free will or random will) vs determinism in the future.

so for the sake of an answer first I need to know the how the neurons get stronger, of course if "stronger" is the suitable term? so is it possible now to detect that some neurons have got stronger? So if the answer is yes, what are those changes like? is it like that we observe some reformations in the structures of their molecules or it's more like that some packets of some materials which I don't have any clue, maybe some chemical materials getting attached to them?

if the detection of physical changes in neurons is not possible right now, what are the predictions of doing this?

I have the same question also for how the brain memorises things or better said stores the memories?

Comment: I don't know if "stronger" is a suitable term, what do you *mean* by it? We talk about *synapses between neurons* getting weaker or stronger, but what do you mean by a "stronger neuron"? If you're making up the term, how should anyone else be able to make sense of it?

Comment: exactly thats why I wrote it with precaution, and I probably meant synapses!! so I mean neuron reacts more to the signals.

Comment: Ok. Yes, that's something that is measured all the time. Look at "long term potentiation" on Wikipedia, for example. The rest of your question still doesn't make a lot of sense, though. What's the connection to free will?

Comment: so if we know how they physically get stronger, maybe later or even now they can make a brain with the same informations of one brain at time t. so by havings so many of that brain at same state we may check the randomness of feedback answers.

Comment: I think you're missing a few very important steps...even if you could make two networks with exactly the same synaptic weights, you can't make them in the same state in the universe. You could certainly make two networks *in silico* that behave the same way, but that doesn't really test free will either.

Comment: btw if its possible can u highlight the parts of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_potentiation that has information about physical changes, cause I'm an engineer and not a biologist

Comment: I think you should try to read and understand the whole thing. If you want to understand biology, it's not really fair to sit behind a wall of "I'm an engineer so I can't learn this". Kind of offensive, really, like if someone asked "how do you build this machine?" and they sent you a book explaining how to do so, and you responded "I'm a biologist not an engineer, can you just tell me the important parts?"

Comment: I think u r right and it only can differentiate between determined vs (random or free will)

Comment: all I understood is there is need for future experiments and knowledge but the answer is yes and some packets as I said or mediators or modulators play role in physical changes in receptors. I will reread it later but if im wrong correct me now. btw just now realized that the computer simulation for testing randomness or being deterministic is impossible. and probably 100 years behind to replicate the brain physically.